# How to make a brush like this one?

Tags: brush

I want to create a brush similiar as the one used for drawing the outline in this picture:
[image]

The softwares I use to draw are FireAlpaca and GIMP, then I'm looking for a solution that can be carried out on those softwares. Thank you in advance for your suggestions !

Comment: Brush like what? I would not speculate that a *single* brush was used in that image.

Comment: If I were to break apart the elements that make the brush, it looks like it could be a round brush with just a little bit feathering or blurriness on the edges and a texture on top. Obviously pen pressure support as well. — But... FireAlpaca and Gimp would both be the last applications I would try if other options fail for some reason. Out of the free options, I'd recommend Krita. It has [good settings for customizing brushes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dcP0Qcoqwvo) and you can find many good [brush packs](https://conceptartempire.com/free-krita-brushes/) from google (and tutorials).

Comment: I don't have access to Krita at the moment, but I think that the thicker 4B pencil brush from the default brushes in Krita might come really close to that style.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Have you tried the MyPaint Brushes in GIMP?  There are several that could create that textured/natural media feel. Have a look at the watercolour and acrylic brushes,

Comment: Thank you @Joonas for recomending Krita, just instaled it and you are right, even the set brushes are perfect for what I want !

Comment: I'll loke for those brushes on GIMP @BillyKerr thank you very much for suggesting !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information, I can't comment much on this particular brush, but most "anime" brushes I've encountered are just captured dabs set to rotate based on the direction the brush is going. The brush is likely not square in its dimensions, with the "direction" side being longer. The edges are semi-transparent, and the interval between dabs can be adjusted to make it more "sketchy" by not having them cleanly meld into each other when switching direction or increasing velocity.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer !